# Вывод трафика в Label

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Код может немного кривой, но все таки, как вывести трафик в Label'ы, а не в ListBox?

```
unit dnip;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Winsock, ExtCtrls, Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Label12: TLabel;
    Label13: TLabel;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  stop_traf: boolean;
  count,trafbitin,trafbitout,trafbitold: integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//////////////////////////////////// Трафик

type
 TMibIfRow = packed record
  wszName          : array[0..255] of WideChar;
  dwIndex          : DWORD;
  dwType           : DWORD;
  dwMtu            : DWORD;
  dwSpeed          : DWORD; // определяет текущую скорость передачи в битах в секунду
  dwPhysAddrLen    : DWORD;
  bPhysAddr        : array[0..7] of Byte; // содержит физический адрес интерфейса (если проще то его, немного видоизмененный, МАС адрес)
  dwAdminStatus    : DWORD;
  dwOperStatus     : DWORD;
  dwLastChange     : DWORD;
  dwInOctets       : DWORD; // содержит количество байт принятых через интерфейс
  dwInUcastPkts    : DWORD;
  dwInNUCastPkts   : DWORD;
  dwInDiscards     : DWORD;
  dwInErrors       : DWORD;
  dwInUnknownProtos: DWORD;
  dwOutOctets      : DWORD; // содержит количество байт отправленных интерфейсом
  dwOutUCastPkts   : DWORD;
  dwOutNUCastPkts  : DWORD;
  dwOutDiscards    : DWORD;
  dwOutErrors      : DWORD;
  dwOutQLen        : DWORD;
  dwDescrLen       : DWORD;
  bDescr           : array[0..255] of Char; // cодержит описание интерфейса
 end;
 TMibIfArray = array [0..512] of TMibIfRow;
 PMibIfRow = ^TMibIfRow;
 PMibIfArray = ^TMibIfArray;

type
 TMibIfTable = packed record
   dwNumEntries: DWORD;
   Table       : TMibIfArray;
 end;
 PMibIfTable = ^TMibIfTable;

var
 GetIfTable:function(pIfTable: PMibIfTable; pdwSize: PULONG;
                              bOrder: Boolean): DWORD; stdcall;

//////////////////////////////////// Интерфейсы

function WSAIoctl(s: TSocket; cmd: DWORD; lpInBuffer: PCHAR; dwInBufferLen:
 DWORD;
 lpOutBuffer: PCHAR; dwOutBufferLen: DWORD;
 lpdwOutBytesReturned: LPDWORD;
 lpOverLapped: POINTER;
 lpOverLappedRoutine: POINTER): integer; stdcall; external 'WS2_32.DLL';

const
 SIO_GET_INTERFACE_LIST = $4004747F;
 IFF_UP = $00000001;
 IFF_BROADCAST = $00000002;
 IFF_LOOPBACK = $00000004;
 IFF_POINTTOPOINT = $00000008;
 IFF_MULTICAST = $00000010;

type
 sockaddr_gen = packed record
  AddressIn: sockaddr_in;
  filler: packed array [0..7] of char;
end;

type
 INTERFACE_INFO = packed record
  iiBroadcastAddress: sockaddr_gen; // Broadcast адрес
  iiNetmask: sockaddr_gen; // Маска подсети
end;

function BytesToString(Value: integer): string;
const
 OneKB=1024;
 OneMB=OneKB*1024;
 OneGB=OneMB*1024;
begin
 if Value<OneKB
 then Result:=FormatFloat('#,##0.00 B',Value)
 else
  if Value<OneMB
  then Result:=FormatFloat('#,##0.00 KB', Value/OneKB)
  else
   if Value<OneGB
   then Result:=FormatFloat('#,##0.00 MB', Value/OneMB)
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
 FLibHandle: THandle;
 Table: TMibIfTable;
 i, Size: integer;
 s,trafnormin,trafnormout: string;
begin
 Timer1.Enabled:=false; // приостанавливаем на всякий случай таймер
 ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
 ListBox1.Items.Clear; // очищаем список
 FLibHandle:=LoadLibrary('IPHLPAPI.DLL'); // загружаем библиотеку
 if FLibHandle=0
 then Exit;
 @GetIfTable:=GetProcAddress(FLibHandle, 'GetIfTable');
 if not Assigned(GetIfTable)
 then
  begin
   FreeLibrary(FLibHandle);
   Close;
  end;

 Size:=SizeOf(Table);
 if GetIfTable(@Table,@Size,false)=0
 then // выполняем функцию
  i:=3; 
   begin
    with ListBox1.Items do
     begin // выводим результаты
      // if string(GetMAC(TMAC(Table.Table[i].bPhysAddr),Table.Table[i].dwPhysAddrLen))<>'00-00-00-00-00-00' // сравнение MAC адресов
      // then
       begin
        // перевод к нормальным единицам "Входящего" трафика
        trafbitin:=Table.Table[i].dwInOctets; // всего принято байт
        trafnormin:=BytesToString(trafbitin);
        // перевод к нормальным единицам "Исходящего" трафика
        trafbitout:=Table.Table[i].dwOutOctets; // всего отправлено байт
        trafnormout:=BytesToString(trafbitout);
        /////////////////////////////////////
        Add('In (Byte): '+trafnormin); // всего принято байт
        Add('Out (Byte): '+trafnormout); // всего отправлено байт
        end;
     end;
   end;
 ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
 FreeLibrary(FLibHandle);
 Timer1.Enabled:=true; // не забываем активировать таймер
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эти строки отвечают за добавление результатов в ListBox

```
Add('In (Byte): '+trafnormin); // всего принято байт
Add('Out (Byte): '+trafnormout); // всего отправлено байт
```

То есть примерно выглядеть будет так

```
  Label1.Caption:= 'In (Byte): '+trafnormin; // всего принято байт
  Label2.Caption:= 'Out (Byte): '+trafnormout; // всего отправлено байт
```

Comment: Естественно весь не нужный код относящийся к ListBox нужно удалить.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал!